# How to Remove Heads Up notifications programatically in Android Studio?

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, notification-listener, notificationservices

I have researched a lot about this but I cannot find a single working solution. I want my app to disable all notification not by a button or something but automatically. I'm developing an app which have a silent screen i.e. the screen is black but notifications are freaking me out. I have tried NotificationListener so that it cancels them automatically whenever it is posted but doesn't work for me. Is there someone genius who can solve my problem?

```
public class NotificationListenerEx extends NotificationListenerService {

public BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationListenerEx.this.cancelAllNotifications();
    }
};


@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("Msg", "Notification Removed");
    return super.onBind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.test.app"));
}
```

}

**Services in Manifest file**

```
        <service android:name=".NotificationListenerEx"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
        >
        </service>
```

**Then to trigger it automatically I put it into onStart()**

```
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.test.app"));
```

Answer (score 1):

From Android 9 It's restricted to handle other outer notification which send by the other applications. Your not able to access that method when its Fire notifications.

Comment: so what is the solution then? And same code doesn't work on pre Android 9 devices.

Comment: its access issue which now not available now its restricted